# My javascript is too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, jquery-plugins

My JavaScript code makes my website to much slow, I don't know what I can do, maybe optimize it but i did it and compressed the JS files too.

Someone can help me?

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // opacity #citation
    var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({ blocks:'.scrollblock' });
    scrollorama.animate('#citation',
    { delay: 5, duration: 250, property:'opacity', start:1 
});

//PARRALAX
$('#nav').localScroll(800);
$('#first_nav').localScroll(800);
RepositionNav();
$(window).resize(function(){
    RepositionNav();
}); 

$('#intro').parallax("50%", 0, 0.1, true);
$('#first').parallax("50%", 0, 0.0, false);
$('#second').parallax("50%", 0, 0.1, true);

$('#third').parallax("50%", 0, 0.3, true);

$('#fourth').parallax("50%", 0, 0.3, true);
    $('.work3').parallax("70%", 6800, 0.1, true);
$('#six').parallax("50%", 0, 0.3, true);
    $('.work4').parallax("20%", 7800, 0.1, true);

// SCROLL EFFECT
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#titre_p h2').stop().animate({ width: "60px", opacity: 0, fontSize: "0em"}, 500 );   
        }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $('#titre_p h2').stop().animate({ width: "190px", opacity: 0, fontSize: "0em"}, 500 );   
        }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 310) {
        $('#titre_p h2').stop().animate({ width: "190px", opacity: 1, fontSize: "1.9em"}, 100 );
        }
    /*titre_2*/
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#titre_p2 h2').stop().animate({ width: "0px", opacity: 0, fontSize: "0em"}, 500 );   
        }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1360) {
        $('#titre_p h2').stop().animate({ width: "190px", opacity: 0, fontSize: "0em"}, 500 );   
        }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1370) {
        $('#titre_p2 h2').stop().animate({ width: "190px", opacity: 1, fontSize: "1.9em"}, 500 );
        }


    $('.work1').parallax("70%", 3740, 0.2, true);   
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1558) {
           $('.work1').parallax("70%", 2820, 0.8, true);   
    }

    $('.work2').parallax("23%", 5950, 2.1, true);        
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2528) {
        $('.work2').parallax("23%", 3798, 2.8, true);   
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1370) {
        $("#work").removeClass('out').addClass('in'); 
    }   

})
})
```

Comment: For us to help, please can you make your question a lot more specific. What part of the JavaScript is slow?

Comment: Also you should tell us what the code actually do or is supposed to do.

Comment: What is the `parallax()` function ? a plugin ?

Comment: @ManseUK: http://stephband.info/jparallax/ . Anyway I think switching from IE6 will make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the animate() method on the scroll event. This event is fired constantly while the user drags the scrollbar. This causes a lot of animate() calls which are very expensive.

It's hard to tell what effect exactly you want to create just by looking at your code, so I can't suggest you an alternative. Would you like to elaborate about what you want to achieve?

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. So I want to accumulate two things :
- parallax effect ($('#intro').parallax("50%", 0, 0.1, true);
)
- and when you scrolling some things happen at a defined pixel from top(if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2528) ...) 

When I accumulate the two effects, it's like that : 
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2528) {
        $('.work2').parallax("23%", 3798, 2.8, true);   
    }
So I just want to stop or change the parralax effect at a defined pixel from the scrolling